# Google Stackdriver supports logging with Log4j for Compute Engine?

Tags: java, log4j, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-logging

My existing Maven code is integrated with Log4j logging and is present on Google Compute Engine and I want to export my logs (Log4j) to Stackdriver, which I am not able to do yet. Also, there is no information available on this in official document (It only explains for `java.util.logging` or logback or fluentd). Is using a different logger the only way?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java Doc?

Comment: I went through it earlier, but it explains nothing about log4j

Comment: You should always link the documents you refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am no expert on Java or log4j, one avenue you could explore is using a combination of log4j and fluentd if you feel you must use log4j.

It's possible to configure fluentd to export custom logs to Stackdriver. When you do this, all that is happening is fluentd is confgured to watch a log file in a specified location, then it formats the contents and exports it to Stackdriver.

If you are able to output the logs of log4j to a file on the VM, then configure fluentd to utilise this file, you may be able to configure it to export the logs to Stackdriver logging. However, if you are going to go to the trouble of customizing both log4j and fluentd for this purpose, then maybe using one of the recommend logging options in the link you've been [reading](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java) would make more sense and be much less time consuming.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/agent-logs#custom_types) for information on how to export custom logs to Stackdriver.